# How to Render Data to the DOM using vue-cli

Tags: templates, vue.js, components, vue-cli

I have created a template:

```
<template>
<div>
<slot></slot>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
   return {
    isShowing: false 
   }
 },
methods: {
toggleShow: function() {
  this.isShowing = !this.isShowing;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.toggleShow1();
  }, 800);
  }
}
<script>

<style>
  ..
</style>
```

And in the HTML document i'd like to toggle a heading only when isShowing is set to true:

```
<div v-if="isShowing">
   <div>
       <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

But then i get this error: ReferenceError: isShowing is not defined

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using v-if outside of Vue? How are you using vue-cli? What are you using webpack or browserify? There's not enough here for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: @jostrander yes i am using v-if outside of Vue and i am using webpack to bundle all my scripts. I am also not using vuex or vue-router.

Comment: the object being returned in the `data` method does not have a closing bracket `}`

Comment: @thanksd just added the missing bracket above. Thanks for pointing that out. However, the issue remains.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the relationship between the component's template (with the slot) and the HTML snippet at the bottom of your post?

Comment: @DecadeMoon the slot is in main.js and the HTML snippet a the bottom is in index.html. main.js gets compiled to bundled.js which then gets added to index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a data of vue instance outside of itself. `isShowing` can only be used inside the `<template>` of the same `.vue` file.

For example:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div v-if="isShowing">
    <slot></slot>
 </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
   return {
    isShowing: false 
   }
 },
methods: {
toggleShow: function() {
  this.isShowing = !this.isShowing;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.toggleShow1();
  }, 800);
  }
}
<script>

<style>
  ..
</style>
```

Comment: But since i am importing all the functionality into the index.html file, can't i just use <name-of-template><h1>Main Heading here</h1></name-of-template> and then the template NameOfTemplate.vue (the one above) would take care of the rest?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. Using isShowing is index.html throws 'isShowing not defined' error.